# "vanquished" as a noun

Tags: past-participles, nominalization

Excerpted from [chronicle.com](http://chronicle.com/article/Is-Philosophy-Obsolete-/145837/):

> Plato gave arguments for why Greeks, under the pressures of war, couldn’t treat other Greeks in abominable ways, pillaging and razing their cities and taking **the vanquished** as slaves.

Though these sentences read fluently and are understandable, I think grammatically it should be **those vanquished**, because it then can be paraphrased to **those who are vanquished**. If it uses **the**, then **vanquished** become **a noun** which it's not.

Am I correct? Or it's OK to use like the original.

Comment: I don't know about "correctness"... but it's done all the time... so it's certainly acceptable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usage of a **verbal noun** is **correct** in the original example

> those **vanquished** are called **the vanquished**.
>
> those  **chosen** are called **the chosen**

**the** is necessary to change the **adjective**

> those who are **vanquished**
>   those who are **chosen**

into a **noun**

> the **vanquished**
>   the **chosen**

either can be used without loss of understanding

> the **vanquished** as slaves
>
> those **vanquished** as slaves
>   those who were **vanquished** as slaves

the same is true for

> **the young
>
>   the old
>
>   the rich
>
>   the poor
>
>   the homeless
>
>   the 1%
>
>   the English**